# How do i display query result in multiline text box in next line c#

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am trying to display my data in multiline textbox like this

```
col1  

result

col2

result

col3

result
```

but I am unable to do it. This is my code

```
SqlConnection sq = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from table",sq);
sq.Open();

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
   // pkg_details.Text = pkg_details.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
    pkg_details.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
    pkg_details.Text = rdr[1].ToString();
    pkg_details.Text = rdr[2].ToString();
}
```

This code displays only one column result. How can I get all of the columns?

Comment: Use a StringBuilder class to Append the text loaded from your reader. At the end of each loop add an Environment,NewLine. At the loop exit set the Text property to the StringBuilder.ToString result

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your current code is that you are overwriting `Text` for every column, so only last column will remain.

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    pkg_details.Text += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rdr.Take(3).Select(ToString));
}
```

if you want to format your columns then try something like

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    pkg_details.Text += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rdr.Take(3)
                  .Select((x, i) => $"Column {i}{Environment.NewLine}{x.ToString()}"));
}
```

but I suggest you to use more appropriate control view to show content, instead of Mutiline textbox. something like list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can make correction in your code following this :

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from table",sq);
        sq.Open();

       SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       while (rdr.Read())
       {
          // pkg_details.Text = pkg_details.Text = rdr[0].ToString();
           pkg_details.Text += rdr[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
           pkg_details.Text += rdr[1].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
           pkg_details.Text += rdr[2].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
       }
```